# Pass data from objects to an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I try to make a chart of the exchange rate, I make a request to the bank and get an array of objects with data about the rate. And I need to transfer the values ​​from the objects to the array that is displayed on the chart

Here I get an array of objects
dateArr={

`0: {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "06.09.2019"}
1: {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "07.09.2019"}
2: {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "08.09.2019"}}`

```js
 var dataArr = [];
async function currency(e) {

var sdate=startdate.value.split("-").join("");
var edate=enddate.value.split("-").join("");
 for (var i = Number(sdate); i <= Number(edate); i++){
 await delay(2000)
 let url=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=${currenc.value}&date=${i}&json`;
let response= await fetch(url);
let data =await response.json();
var itemObj={
 rate:data[0].rate,
 exchangedate:data[0].exchangedate
 };
 dataArr.push(itemObj);
}
console.log(dataArr);

}
```

And here I need to pass the data field to the series array
data[25.31,25.31,25.31]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Графік курса валют'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Зріст'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: []        //OVER HERE!!!
    }, {
       
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly... If your array variable "dataArr" is accessible in this context you can assign data: dataArr like this:

You can extract the rate values out of the array into a new array like this:

```
var dateArr = [{rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "06.09.2019"}, {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "07.09.2019"}]
var rates = dateArr.map(x => x.rate)
# rates is now [25.310639, 25.310639]
```

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Графік курса валют'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Зріст'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: rates        //OVER HERE!!!
    }, {

    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Comment: Yes, but dateArr has objects, and objects have fields
`0: {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "06.09.2019"}
1: {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "07.09.2019"}`
, and I need to pass `rate` values ​​in the data field on the diagram

Comment: Updated my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get the array of objects like below then simply use map function to getthe rate field values.

```
arr = [
    {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "06.09.2019"},
    {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "07.09.2019"},
    {rate: 25.310639, exchangedate: "08.09.2019"}
];
newData = arr.map(d => d.rate);
console.log(newData);
```